# Error when trying to reclassify raster to no data using Python

Tags: python, numpy, raster, any

I'm trying to reclassify my raster using python and it works via the script below...

```
import gdal  # raster management
import ogr  # vector managment
import numpy as np  # gridded data
import os  # file managment
import csv  # for saving results in csv format
from osgeo import gdal

import numpy as np  # gridded data
from osgeo import gdal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
file = gdal.Open('Extract_2.tif')

gt = file.GetGeoTransform()
proj = file.GetProjection()
band = file.GetRasterBand(1)
lista = band.ReadAsArray()

file.RasterCount

binmask2 = np.where(((41 > lista) & (lista > 49)),np.nan,1)
```

However now, instead of reclassing all values between 41 and 49 as equal to 1, I want to make it so that 41 = 1, 43= 1, and 49=1, and keep it so that all others = np.nan.  So I changed the last line to this:

```
 binmask = np.where(((lista == 41) & (lista == 43) & (lista == 49)),1,np.nan)
```

This ends up creating an empty tiff. I tried changing the "&" to "or"...

```
binmask = np.where(((lista == 41) or (lista == 43) or (lista == 49)),1,np.nan)
```

But that gives me this error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 0):

If & works for "and" in numpy, you can safely assume that | will work for "or"

binmask = np.where(((lista == 41) |(lista == 43) |(lista == 49)),1,np.nan)